# onClickListener on PaneTemplate not allowed?

Tags: android, android-auto

I have a simple PaneTemplate I am setting up like this:

```
Row row1 = new Row.Builder().setTitle("Do Thing 1").build();
Row row2 = new Row.Builder().setTitle("Do Thing 2").build();
Row row3 = new Row.Builder().setTitle("Do Thing 3").build();
Row row4 = new Row.Builder().setTitle("Do Thing 4").build();
return new PaneTemplate.Builder(new Pane.Builder().addRow(row1).addRow(row2).addRow(row3).addRow(row4).build()).setTitle("AA Hello!!").build();
```

and it all works fine and looks like this:

[image]

but if I add setOnClickListener to one of the rows:

```
Row row1 = new Row.Builder().setTitle("Do Thing 1").setOnClickListener(this::onClick).build();
```

I get an exception:
"a click listener is not allowed on the row"

[image]

I get an error:

I have not read about this restriction in any of the AA documentation.  I tried making the onClick function anything number of things, including a blank function, and it makes no difference.  Any idea what is going on here?  How can I get around it?  I want the press of this item to do something.

Answer (score 1):

It's restricted on `PaneTemplate`.

Using `ListTemplate` for such simple list is better decision.

Comment: I preliminarily tried that and it worked!  I can add an onClickListener to a row in a ListTemplate and it works.  If someone could point me to the docs where it says what is and is not allowed on the different templates I'd appreciate it.

Comment: read the requirements https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/model/PaneTemplate.Builder#requirements